# How to create a Tornado chart in Power BI with one fixed organization and the ability for the user to change the other organization

Tags: powerbi-desktop

Hi There i am visualizing two organization performance in different categories using tornado chart and i want one organization to be fixed and other one user can change. how to do that.

For example i want in below visual newman university to be default and other one user can change.

[Visual Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE3ex.png)

i tried making two filter one for report level and another one for visual level but that did'nt worked